# Multiple Tikz-Trees in a subfigure-grouped figure row

Tags: tikz, subfigure

How to put multiple Tikz trees in a subfigure-grouped figure row? As the provided screenshot indicates, every figure/ tree is put in a separate row. I guess that the tree width is > 50% of the line width, but I don't know one can regulate the width of a tikz tree figure...

[image]

```
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{figure}[H]

\subfigure[s1]{
\begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{0.5\textwidth}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree[.{root} ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\centering{}
\end{minipage}}\qquad

\subfigure[s2]{
\begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{0.5\textwidth}%
\centering{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ ]

\Tree[.{another root} ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}}

   \caption{the caption}
 \end{figure}
```

**EDIT: request to move this topic to tex.stackexchange.com** - sorry, was on the wrong page ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the blank line between the lines

```
\end{minipage}}\qquad

\subfigure[s2]{
```

does the trick...